# Accessing child property inside an array list of base class

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I am trying to access the property of the child class inside an array list of the base class

```
ArrayList<Parent> listValue = new ArrayList<Parent>();
listValue.add(new Child1());
listValue.add(new Child2());
```

This is the class parent

```
class Parent{
String name;
public Parent(String name){
  this.name = name
  }
}
```

This is the child class

```
class Child extends Parent{
String childOnly;

public Child(String name){
super(name);
 }
}
```

And i am trying to access the class property somehow like this

```
string value = listValue.get(1).childOnly
```

Comment: How come you are adding `Child` objects to a `List` of `Parent`s? does `Child` extend `Parent`? if so better update your question.

Comment: I forgot to put the extends. It is fixed now. Thank you ;)

Comment: it doesn't work like this because `listValue` is a list of `Parent` objects. `Parent` does not have the property `childOnly`. You would need to cast the object first: (Child) listValue.get(1).childOnly

Comment: You may want to mark any of the answers below as the solution to help others with the same question finding a solution quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Specify that your list contains any subclass of Parent, like this:

```
List<? extends Parent> listValue = new ArrayList<>();
```

2. Cast you object when fetching from the list, like this:

```
if (listValue.get(1) instanceof Child)
{
    Child child = (Child) listValue.get(1);
    String value = child.childOnly;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check and cast:

```
Parent obj = listValue.get(1);
if(obj instanceof Child)
{
    chld Child = (Child)obj;
    string value = chld.childOnly;
...
```